# How to delete a repository in subversion edge?

Tags: svn, repository, sharpsvn, subversion-edge

Seems like the Subversion Edge Restful API isn't able to (completely) delete a repository - only to create one. Also, sharpSvn seems to work only on repositorly-level and lower, which means, no deletion of repository also...
So is there a way to **programmatically** remove a repository in Subversion Edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no option to delete a repository using only the uberSVN APIs. This is an administrative task, one that is best accomplished using the command line tool "rm". Removing a repository is the same as removing a folder on a file system.

The creation of a repository was always a strange one to me, I don't think it should be part of the normal uberSVN APIs anyway, as it too is a admin-level task that gets used infrequently.

Comment: Thanks a lot! could you please elaborate on this?
I only know to use the api's, so a code example can be very helpful here..

Comment: uberSvn has an API and SvnEdge has an api, but these aren't the same APIs. Both are supported by different companies.